# EmberJS: What's the difference between get(obj, 'prop') and obj.get('prop')?

Tags: ember.js

There are two ways in EmberJs to retrieve object's property.

You can either use `myObject.get('propertyName')`, which is more common, or you can use `get(myObject, 'propertyName')`

Is there any implementation difference between these two? Or is one of them just a shortcut to the other? Are there any performance benefits/costs?

Comment: As long as `myObject` is an `Ember.Object`, there is no difference. However, Ember can work with POJOs as well, which don't have `this.get` method.

Comment: Have a look at [this discussion](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/definitive-guide-of-when-to-use-get/6789)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In practice sometimes when you work with JSONs coming from API you get plain and simple JavaScript objects which don't inherit properties from `Ember.Object`. It means that you don't have access also to `myObject.get()` method.

```
let myObject = {};
myObject.get === undefined // true

// this means you can't use myObject.get('propertyName')
```

That's when you either use `myObject.propertyName` or `Ember.get(myObject, 'propertyName')`:

```
let myObject = { propertyName: 666 };
let propertyValue = Ember.get(myObject, 'propertyName');
alert(propertyValue); // works
```

Comment: well, if I get plain JSON objects via xhr request, then it probably means that I've not used adapters/serializers propertly. But I get your point.

Comment: Yes, however reality is it's common case in Ember applications. ;)